# Remove class of a clicked element in a hover event if a second element has been clicked

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to do following:
If I click on an ul li element of a navigation (see example below) then the selected li increases of 100 width with transition effect. 
If I click again on the clicked **li** its width does not change.
But, if click on another **li** the previous clicked **li** element must be set to the initial width of 24px (removing the active class) if I pass hover with the mouse.
In the example below the first selected li does not change.
This is the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/maeewLhs/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.b-square > li').click(function() {
        var linkName = $(this).data('name');
        $('.b-square > li').removeClass('active').text('');
        $(this).toggleClass('nav');
        $(this).toggleClass('active').text(linkName);
        $(this).unbind("mouseout"); //Remove mouseout event after clicking
    });

    $('.b-square > li').mouseover(function() {
        var linkName = $(this).data('name');

        //If no active class exists in the selected element, then call hover event
        if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).toggleClass('nav');
            $(this).toggleClass('active').text(linkName);
        }
    });

    $('.b-square > li').mouseout(function() {
        var currentID = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).removeClass('active').text('');
    });
});
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to do. Can you rephrase your expected results?

Comment: Hi, I rephrased my epected result. I hope is clearer now.

Comment: I'm still confused about the "if I pass hover with the mouse" part, but is this the behavior you are trying to implement? https://jsfiddle.net/maeewLhs/21/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `mouseout()` use `mouseleave()` so it will end like:

`$('.b-square > li').mouseleave(function(){
         var currentID = $(this).attr('id');`

Then remove the bound function to the linked element (within the click function):

`$(this).unbind("mouseleave");`

`mouseout()` is for div's whereas `mouseleave()` is for "leaving" any element.
forgot to remove the binding to the event on click, the updated fiddle should work:
here's the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maeewLhs/10/)

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem. Hovering over the other elements doesn't remove the `active` class from the clicked element.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately I have the same issue. If I click on two different li the width current li does not change (that's fine), but the previous must be set to the initial width of 24px.

Comment: For some reason it seems really buggy when clicking over them quickly, not too up to date with my JS/Jquery knowledge to sort that one out unfortunately, will have a play

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
$(".b-square > li.active").removeClass("active nav").text("").mouseout(function() {
    var currentID = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).removeClass('active').text('');
});
```

To your `mouseover` handler.

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maeewLhs/41/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately I have the same issue. If I click on two different li the width current li does not change (that's fine), but the previous must be set to the initial width of 24px.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It's working now. I forgot to rebind `mouseout`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want, try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.b-square > li').click(function() {
        var linkName = $(this).data('name');
        $('.b-square > li.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        $('.b-square > li:not(.selected)').removeClass('active');
        $('.b-square > li:not(.selected)').text('');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('nav');
        $(this).text(linkName);        

    });

    $('.b-square > li').mouseover(function() {
        var linkName = $(this).data('name');

        //If no active class exists in the selected element, then call hover event
        if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).toggleClass('nav');
            $(this).toggleClass('active').text(linkName);
        }
    });

    $(document).on('mouseout','.b-square > li:not(.selected)',function() {
        var currentID = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).removeClass('active').text('');
    });
});
```

I created a select class to distinguish active(mouseover) and clicked, although clicked items use active class as well.

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maeewLhs/44/)

### Edited

Edited after [Stevie P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1788411/steve-p) corrected me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36796447/remove-class-of-a-clicked-element-in-a-hover-event-if-a-second-element-has-been/36797381?noredirect=1#comment61169420_36797381).

Comment: `$('.b-square > li.selected').removeClass('selected');` <- add that just before the `$(this).toggleClass('selected');` and that will sort it :) wasn't removing the "selected" class from the other elements once you had clicked another one, other than that was all good.

Comment: Yeah, after I've read again the question, I saw my mistake! New [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maeewLhs/44/)